# AKS azure/application-gateway health annotations doesn't update the health probe in Application Gateway

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure Application Gateway with AKS, where I have created the ingress object with following annotations.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "myingress"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/path/"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-hostname: "myhost"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-port: "myport"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: "/path/health"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-status-codes: "200-399, 403"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-interval: "20"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-timeout: "15"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-unhealthy-threshold: "5"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "myhost"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /something/path/*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: "myservice"
            port:
              number: "8080"
```

However, I don't see this information passed on to the app gateway.

```
-- App Gwy config --            {
-- App Gwy config --                "id": "/subscriptions/mysubscription/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/mygateway/probes/pb-ns-myservice-8080-myingress",
-- App Gwy config --                "name": "pb-ns-myservice-8080-myingress",
-- App Gwy config --                "properties": {
-- App Gwy config --                    "host": "myhost",
-- App Gwy config --                    "interval": 30,
-- App Gwy config --                    "match": {},
-- App Gwy config --                    "minServers": 0,
-- App Gwy config --                    "path": "/path/health",
-- App Gwy config --                    "pickHostNameFromBackendHttpSettings": false,
-- App Gwy config --                    "protocol": "Http",
-- App Gwy config --                    "timeout": 30,
-- App Gwy config --                    "unhealthyThreshold": 3
-- App Gwy config --                }
-- App Gwy config --            }
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above mentioned annotations are available in AGIC version number 1.4.0.[Github Issue #1178](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/1178) 
To check the version number, run the following command:

```
k describe pod -l app=ingress-azure -n kube-system | grep "Image:"
```

**Result**: Image:          mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress:1.4.0 
Validate the version number it should be 1.4.0 or higher.

**Note**: Though AKS-AGIC addon automatically deploys the latest version of AGIC. However, it doesn't upgrade the required version as of today. You need to manually upgrade the AGIC version via Helm charts. Follow steps mentioned in below link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-existing#install-ingress-controller-as-a-helm-chart

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as the TS, but I also DO have 1.4.0 installed and running:

```yaml
Containers:
  ingress-azure:
    Container ID: containerd://c2d74b1e8ca81394c85d9e5c484f125020d0f7c2ce07872bf1fc9d5bb15e317a
    Image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress:1.4.0
    Image ID: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-application-gateway/kubernetes-ingress@sha256:ae323e343be86e04bd74bdb707bf0e027a17ccf0423435a51cdaac0c13072e6b
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Interesting. Can you please validate in azure > your-resource-group > application-gateway > health-probe(from left menu) > ingress-object. If you see the configuration you provided in ingress-object is reflecting or not. 
If not, check if AKS is really connected with application-gateway. You need to create the network peering between application-gateway and AKS cluster.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing#peer-the-two-virtual-networks-together
Note: AKS resides in it's own resource group separate than application-gateway.

Comment: A lot changed, we're now running v1.5.2, rolled back to v1.5.1 to sort out an issue where the appgw kept 'dropping' https listeners randomly, which is a different issue altoghther. I haven;t checked now, but am assuming the provided annotations do work now.